# Is there an easier way to input a lot of possible parameters into an else if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I'm creating a game kind of like twenty one questions. The user is asked to think of a word: Food, Animal, or Object. The computer then asks a bunch of questions before eventually coming to the conclusion of what the word should be.

Currently, I've got the code for the most part worked out like this:

```
 //Guesses the animal based on given answers
        if (a1.equals("Animal")) {
            if (aA1.equals("Small") && aAs1.equals("Small") && aA2.equals("Land") && aA3.equals("No") && aA4 == 4 && (aAld1.equals("Plains") | aAld1.equals("Cities")) && (aA5.equals("Fur") | aA5.equals("Hair")) && aA6.equals("Yes") && (aAld2.equals("No"))) {
                System.out.println("Mouse!");
                /*
                Size: Small, Small
                Domain: Land
                Wings: No
                Legs: 4
                Home: Plains | Cities
                Skin Type: Fur | Hair
                Common Pet: Yes
                Domesticated: No
                 */
            } else if (aA1.equals("Small") && aAs1.equals("Small") && aA2.equals("Water") && aAw1.equals("Most") && aA3.equals("No") && aA4 == 0  && aA5.equals("Scales") && aA6.equals("Yes")) {
                System.out.println("Fish!");
                /*
                Size: Small, Small
                Domain: Water
                Body of Water: Most
                Wings: No
                Legs: 0
                Skin Types: Scales
                Common Pet: Yes
                 */
            } else if (aA1.equals("Large") && aA2.equals("Water") && (aAw1.equals("Oceans") | aAw1.equals("Seas")) && aA3.equals("No") && aA4 == 0  && aA5.equals("Skin") && aAl1.equals("Dangerous") && aA6.equals("No")) {
                System.out.println("Shark!");
                /*
                Size: Large
                Domain: Water
                Body of Water: Oceans | Seas
                Wings: No
                Legs: 0
                Skin Type: Skin
                Danger Level: Dangerous
                Common Pet: No
                 */
            } else if ((aA1.equals("Small") | aA1.equals("Medium")) && (aAs1.equals("Small") | aAs1 != "Small") && (aA2.equals("Land")) && (aA3.equals("No")) && aA4 == 4 && (aAld1.equals("Cities")) && aAld2.equals("Yes") && aA5.equals("Fur") && aA6.equals("Yes") && aAfc.equals("Feline")) {
                System.out.println("Cat!");
                /*
                Size: Small | Medium, Small | !Small
                Domain: Land
                Wings: No
                Legs: 4
                Home: Cities
                Domesticated: Yes
                Skin Type: Fur
                Common Pet: Yes
                 */
            } else if ((aA1.equals("Small") | aA1.equals("Medium")) && (aAs1.equals("Small") | aAs1 != "Small") && aA2.equals("Land") && aA3.equals("No") && aA4 == 4 && aAld1.equals("Cities") && aAld2.equals("Yes") && aA5.equals("Fur") && aA6.equals("Yes") && aAfc.equals("Canine")) {
                System.out.println("Dog!");
                /*
                Size: Small | Medium, Small | !Small
                Domain: Land
                Wings: No
                Legs: 4
                Home: Cities
                Domesticated: Yes
                Skin Type: Fur
                Common Pet: Yes
                 */
            }else {
                System.out.println("Sorry! That's not an animal we recognize yet. Better luck next time!");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
```

It works fine for the most part, but entering in all of the possible parameters is exhausting, and takes a ridiculous amount of time. Plus, there's still some bugs, which include some questions outputs being "null" due to the fact that they're only asked based on the answer given beforehand. For example, the question "Does it live in the Mountains, Plains, Forests, Deserts, or Cities?" is only asked if the user enters "Land" when asking if it lives on Land, in the Sky, or in the Water. The problem here is that people describe things differently. If the word was "penguin", one person might say water, while another might say land. This messes up the algorithm when guessing if the word is penguin. (Does this make sense? I'm not sure how else to explain it)

Basically, I need to find a way to make the code considerably shorter while also solving the possibly null question output.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwentyOneQuestionsGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Think of a word: Food, Animal, or Object.");

        String[] questions = {
                "Size: Small, Medium, or Large?",
                "Where does it live? Land, Sky, or Water?",
                "If Land, does it live in Mountains, Plains, Forests, Deserts, or Cities?",
                "If Sky, does it have Wings? Yes or No?",
                "If Land, how many Legs does it have?",
                "If Water, what type of Skin does it have?",
                "Is it Dangerous? Yes or No?",
                "Is it a Common Pet? Yes or No?"
        };

        String[] answers = new String[questions.length];
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(questions[i]);
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            answers[i] = input.toLowerCase();
        }

        if (answers[1].equals("land")) {
            if (answers[0].equals("small")) {
                if (answers[2].equals("cities")) {
                    if (answers[3].equals("no") && answers[4].equals("4") && answers[7].equals("yes")) {
                        if (answers[5].equals("fur") || answers[5].equals("hair")) {
                            System.out.println("It's a Cat!");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (answers[2].equals("cities")) {
                    if (answers[3].equals("no") && answers[4].equals("4") && answers[7].equals("yes")) {
                        if (answers[5].equals("fur") || answers[5].equals("hair")) {
                            System.out.println("It's a Dog!");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Sorry! That's not something we recognize yet. Better luck next time!");
    }
}
```

Try using this refactored code. It may not be fully correct but I think you can get a idea.